# Problem with shape of input when using scipy.optimize.minimize for minimizing a function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, portfolio, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to minimize a risk measure for a portfolio of assets with scipy.optimize.minimize. This is done by minimizing a measure of your risk (named ES in this case) by changing the weight of each asset. I have tried scipy.optimize a couple of times with success, but when I run the optimizer it turns my vector of weights into a single number, and I have no idea why...

My arbitrary weights are set, and when I print the weights in the function that is to be minimized it appears as a single number

Code:

```
def ES_calc_sum(pi_bad, weights, mu_good_vector, mu_bad_vector, cov_good_matrix, cov_bad_matrix, alpha):

    print(weights)
    sum = np.sum(risk_contribution(pi_bad, weights, mu_good_vector, mu_bad_vector, cov_good_matrix, cov_bad_matrix, alpha))

    return sum

weights = np.array([0.5,0.25,0.25])

def RC_minimizer(target_vol, weights, pi_bad, mu_good_vector, 
    mu_bad_vector, cov_good_matrix, cov_bad_matrix, alpha):

     bnds = Bounds(0, 1)
     cont = ({"type": "eq", "fun": lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1},
            {"type": "eq", "fun": lambda x: ((1 - pi_bad) * np.sqrt(x @ cov_good_matrix @ x) + pi_bad * np.sqrt(x @ cov_bad_matrix @ x) - target_vol})

     res = minimize(ES_calc_sum, x0 = weights, args = (pi_bad, mu_good_vector, mu_bad_vector, cov_good_matrix, cov_bad_matrix, alpha), method="SLSQP", bounds=bnds, constraints=cont, tol=0.0001)

     w_opt = res.x

     return w_opt
```

Error:

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)
```

help would be greatly appreciated as this code is to be used for my Masters Thesis

Trying to minimize a measure under changing weights.

Comment: I tried to correct the display indentation.  You FORGOT to show the FULL error message, or do any diagnostics related to it.  Since it is `matmul`, I can guess the problem is with one of the `x @ cov_good_matrix @ x` phrases.  What it's saying is the `@` does not work with scalars; it's for array arguments only.

Comment: Consider replacing the `cont` `lambda` with a proper `def`, so you can break up the calculation into several lines, and can add some diagnostic prints.